Oracle - manual replication and force logging
When we configure Data Guard, we enable force logging. If we set up manual replication (via rsync and cataloging the archives at the destination + database recovery), do we need to enable force logging as well?

If you want to avoid problems you should enable force logging, too.
Otherwise it is possible that somebody issues a nologging statement in your database which in case of a restore can’t be recovered on the target database and the object affected by the nologging operation is invalid when you open the target database. You manually have to recreate the object on the target database. This means

you have to drop and recreate the index that you created in nologging mode
You have to truncate and reload the partition that you loaded in
nologging mode
if the table was unpartitioned, you have to export the valid data of the of the table, truncate the table, import the table data again and redo the load
In the case of table and table partitions you probably have to repair
the indexes on this table, too

In case of a manual or automatic dataguard replication you have to make a backup of the affected blocks on the source database and apply this on the target database.
